# vim takes long time to scan tags when complete

Tags: vim

my vim will scanning tags for a long time when press tab to complete.
I don't know it is about plugins or vimrc file.
it really annoy.
my vimrc is:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5591546

it seems when I press tab it even scan the /usr/include directory,it take long time,it makes me crazy.

such when I edit a file like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ioste>
main()
{
    int x = 8;
    float y = 9.0;
    char z = 'a';

    int *p = &x;
    float *q = &y;
    char *r = &z;

    printf("the *p address is %x\n",p);

    printf("%d\n", sizeof(p));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(x));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(y));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(z));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(r));
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(q));
    printf("%c\n", *r);
    printf("%f\n", *q);
}
```

in include
it will begin to tell scanning tags,and vim stuck.

Answer (score 15):

The directories that are scanned for tags databases are configured by the `'tags'` option. You seem to have `/usr/include/**` in there.

The insert mode completion uses the sources configured by the `'complete'` option; by default, this includes tags via the `t` value. You can turn that off with `:set complete-=t`.

Note that you can also abort the lengthy scanning by pressing `<C-c>`.

Comment: you are right,when I press tab,it seems scans the /usr/include/**,I have set complete-=t in vimrc,when I type tab ,it prompt some completion from /usr/include/**,so it seems still scan the /usr/include/**  but seems more quick than before.